# Windowsでのspresense SDKセットアップ

Tags: spresense

§2.2. Windows向けセットアップ
の以下の環境構築を行っています。

[Windows向けセットアップ - Spresense SDK スタートガイド (CLI 版)](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ja.html#_windows%E5%90%91%E3%81%91%E3%82%BB%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97)

`$ bash install-tools.sh` のコマンドが以下のエラーで止まります。

```
== Install base command line tools
== Install additional tools
=== tar xvzf nuttx-tools.tar.gz --strip-components=1 -C nuttx-tools   install-tools.sh: 145 行: cd: nuttx-tools/kconfig-frontends: No such
file or directory tar.exe: Error opening archive: Failed to open
'nuttx-tools/genromfs-0.5.2.tar.gz'
=== ./configure --prefix=/opt/spresenseenv/usr --disable-shared --disable-nconf  
=== make install
```

`install-tools.sh` のL.137の以下でnuttx-tools.tar.gzのファイルサイズが0になっていてダウンロードに失敗していることが原因のようでした。

```
download ${NXTOOLURL}/get/master.tar.gz ${NXTOOLARCHIVE}
```

以下Nuttxツールには、master.tar.gzが見つかりませんでした。
https://bitbucket.org/nuttx/tools/src/master/

恐らく、Nuttxのサイトでファイルの整理が入って、それがspresenseで対応できていない事が原因かと推測しているのですが、
install-tools.shをローカルで編集するとして、どれがmaster.tar.gzなのかを教えてください。

Answer (score 0):

ダウンロードしようとしているのは BitBucket の対象リポジトリ全体をまとめたもので、以下のURLにアクセスすればダウンロードが可能かと思います。
(スクリプトでは保存の際、"nuttx-tools.tar.gz"にリネームしているようです)

https://bitbucket.org/nuttx/tools/get/master.tar.gz

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。教えてもらったURLからダウンロードしてスクリプトを編集して成功しました。  尚、PROXYサーバを設置していない環境ですが、どうも他のファイルでもdownloadコマンドで0バイトのファイルになっていました。これもスクリプトを編集して、wgetに変えることで問題無くダウンロード出来ました。

Comment: `curl` コマンドがインストールされていないのかもしれませんね。

Comment: curl コマンドは、動作するのですが、download コマンドと同様に0バイトのファイルがダウンロードされます。curl もwgetで代用しています。